# Include enum in service reference

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have an enum that I use for processing logic flags and I would like to expose the processing logic through a WCF service to a Silverlight client.

First problem is that if I use Option1 | Option2 (bit flags) the serializer has a problem as the sum of the two options do not equate to an enumerable option (as should be). I can overcome this by using an int as the parameter. This however gets met to my second problem: my enum is not included in the service reference as it is not a member of any type (DataContract).

I can overcome my second problem with a linked file but would prefer not to, or by creating a dummy method that returns the enum type, also not great.

Is there a simple way of desrializing the odd number, or injecting the enum type into the service reference? Or a better option all together?

Comment: I have just found a enum friend called [Flags] which allows me to use the enum as a parameter value and bit flags are deserialized correctly... Can't answer my own question yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found a enum friend called [Flags] which allows me to use the enum as a parameter value and bit flags are deserialized correctly...

Answer (score 0):

For this you should use:

```
[DataContract(Name = "CarCondition")]
public enum CarConditionEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    New,
    [EnumMember]
    Used,
    [EnumMember]
    Rental,
    Broken,
    Stolen
}
```

You can get more details here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question, but led me to the answer, thanks in any case